# Assign value to closest polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to assign values to a polygon shape, according
to another polygon shape taking the closest polygon of the last shape.
I´d prefer to use Arcgis but any software is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attributes of the first polygon in the table of the second polygon, you can apply a spatial join.
With ArcGis and the spatial join tool you got the Match Option that you can set to CLOSEST. There is also WITHIN_A_DISTANCE if you want to join your attributes only within a perimeter.